# Entity Framework - ElementAt

Tags: entity-framework

I have a Table User(ID, Name....), Projects(ID, Name, Timestamps, IsFavorite...), Projects_Favoite(UserID, ProjectID)

I try to check for each projekt if there is a row for the current user. If there is a row I want set the "IsFavorite" in my Project true, otherwise false.

I tied:

```
 for(int i = 0; i <= erg.Count();i++)
 {
     if (erg.ElementAt(i).User11.Any(u => u.Guid == ID) == true) 
         erg.ElementAt(i).SetFavorite = true; 
 }
```

but there is no way to use ElementAt, because it can't translated to SQL.
So I tried:

```
 for(int i = 0; i <= erg.Count();i++)
 {
     if (erg.Take(i).Last().User11.Any(u => u.Guid == ID) == true)
         erg.Take(i).Last().SetFavorite = true; 
 }
```

same problem here, so I tried:

```
foreach (Project project in erg)
{
     if (project.User11.Any(u => u.Guid == ID))
          project.SetFavorite = true;
}
```

There is the same problem. Is there a way to realise a ElementAt?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do:

```
foreach (Project project in erg.Where(p => p.User11.Any(u => u.Guid == ID))
                               .ToList())
    project.SetFavorite = true;
}
```

Comment: Any details? What is the exception message, any inner exception?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that erg is an `IQuerable` than you cannot use ElementAt as it is not supported (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399342.aspx  check the section Operators With no translation), you can use it on a list though, but of course you will lose the benefits of the deferred query. 
Try to use `Skip` instead

```
var whatyouwant = erg.Skip(index).First();
```

By looking at the stacktrace (can't read german though) looks there's something wrong with the SetFavorite column. Try first to **remove** this bit first:

```
 project.SetFavorite = true;
```

then check also that your model columns match with what you got on the db.